# How can I get and replace this in javascript ( jquery?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to manipulate a link href which looks like this:

> /agents/view/model:Member/ag_start_dateMonth:08/ag_start_dateYear:2012/ag_end_dateMonth:08/ag_end_dateYear:2012

I need to catch the part: `ag_start_dateMonth` and replace the value `08` with a value the user selected through a form.

That means, that I need to find where in the string is this pattern `ag_start_dateMonth` and to find the value just after the `:` and before the next `/` and to replace it with a new value given by the user through form select option.

How can I do this?
Please advice, I am quite unsure about regex syntax :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this input come from a form on the page, you can always "Rebuild" the href instead of search and replace. Say you have a form you were getting these values from on the page, with jQuery this would be trivial with something like

```
jQuery('#id-of-form button').click( function () {
    var start_month = jQuery('#id-of-form select.start-month').val();
    var start_year = jQuery('#id-of-form select.start-year').val();
    var end_month = jQuery('#id-of-form select.end-month').val();
    var end_year = jQuery('#id-of-form select.end-year').val();
    jQuery(a#your-link-id).attr('href','/agents/view/model:Member/ag_start_dateMonth:' +
         start_month + '/ag_startdateYear:' + start_year + "/ag_end_dateMonth:" +
         end_month + '/ag_end_dateYear:' + end_year);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
var s = '/agents/view/model:Member/ag_start_dateMonth:08/ag_start_dateYear:2012/ag_end_dateMonth:08/ag_end_dateYear:2012';
var selected = 10;
s = s.replace(/(ag_start_dateMonth:)([0-9]+)/, '$1' + selected);
```

This little handy regular expression maintains two matching groups: one that one might call static, and the other which will contain the date that you want to replace.

Comment: Thank you soo much!! You made my day!! This works just great for me!! Also thanks to everybody!!

Answer (score 1):

This should get you going:

```
var s = '/agents/view/model:Member/ag_start_dateMonth:08/ag_start_dateYear:2012/' +
        'ag_end_dateMonth:08/ag_end_dateYear:2012';
var newText = 'foo';

alert(s.replace(/(ag_start_dateMonth:)08(\/)/, '$1' + newText + '$2'));
```